# How can i add / remove a class to a child tag with different parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done this :

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="type">
    <input type="radio" name="selector" id="uberX" value="1">
    <label for="uberX">Uber X</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="type">
    <input type="radio" name="selector" id="uberSUV" value="2">
    <label for="uberSUV">Uber SUV</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="type">
    <input type="radio" name="selector" id="uberBlack" value="3">
    <label for="uberBlack">Uber Black</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried using this:

```
$('.type label').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.type input').addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
})
```

But since it belong to different **parent tag** so it wont remove the class when **unchecked** so i changed to using this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
  label[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    input[i].classList.add("checked");
  })
}
```

But still didn't work

> ( TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined )

Are there any other ways to add class to the one being checked and remove the others?

Comment: use the id instaed of class .otherwise define separate calss for eash

Comment: $('.type label').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#uberBlack').addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$('.type input').on('change', function(e) {
  $('.type input').removeClass('checked');
  $(this).addClass('checked');
})
```

```css
.checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li class="type">
    <input type="radio" name="selector" id="uberX" value="1">
    <label for="uberX">Uber X</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="type">
    <input type="radio" name="selector" id="uberSUV" value="2">
    <label for="uberSUV">Uber SUV</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li class="type">
    <input type="radio" name="selector" id="uberBlack" value="3">
    <label for="uberBlack">Uber Black</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first guess was close. This should do it:

```
$('.type label').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Remove the 'checked' class from all of my siblings' input fields (including me):
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(
        function() {
            $(this).find('input').removeClass('checked');
        }
    );

    // Add the 'checked' class to my input field:
    $(this).parent().find('input').addClass('checked');
})
```

Comment: just tested with this and found out that i had to remove the 'e.preventDefault()' for it to work but still thank you for the solution